# Не правильно работает определение корабля в морском бое

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, sqlite3

Пишу "Морской бой" и нашел неприятный момент, когда стреляешь в 3 палубный корабль с середины и любую клетку с краю, он уничтожается и 3 клетка где должен быть еще корабль закрывается, с 4 палубным такая же история.

Если вот так расставить корабли
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При самой игре, происходит вот так

я пометил, где еще должен стоять корабль

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

https://github.com/rangihrad/sw.git

извиняюсь, за большой код, но как мог его сократил.

Comment: Можете попонятнее описать проблему

Comment: @rangihrad Честно говоря не понял зачем там база данных прикручена. Хотя к проблеме это не относится.

Comment: @AlexanderChernin есть трех палубный корабль, который занимает 3 клетки в таблице и если выстрелить в середину этого корабля, то есть во 2 клетку корабля, и потом любую другую(1 или 3 клетку корабля), то корабль уничтожиться и все клетки вокруг станут "*" в которые нельзя выстрелить, как сделать так, что бы было нормальное определение корабля, что бы 3 палубный корабль не уничтожался с 2 подбитых клеток.

Comment: @GrAnd я туда записываю расположение кораблей

Comment: Это я понял. Я не понял зачем для этого БД, и почему не достаточно простой переменной.

Comment: @rangihrad Проблема, в принципе, ясна. Но на ваших структурах данных не исправить. Вы сами корабли с их расположением ведь не храните.

Comment: @GrAnd я просто изучаю sqlite и решил попробовать сделать так

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ваша проблема заключалась в том, что вы нигде не храните знания о кораблях. Занятые ячейки поля, что вы храните в `players[].board` - этой информации не достаточно. Потому что, допустим, вы попадаете трехпалубнику в середину, и в результате в `players[].board`он, по сути, "разваливается" на два однопалубника. Отсюда и получается полное потопление при попадании в любую из этих частей-однопалубников.

Итак, во-первых я замучился задавать корабли через ввод координат (честно говоря на третьем корабле). Поэтому я переделал так, что надо выделить нужное количество ячеек таблицы и нажать на кнопку "Поставить корабль". Заодно совместил задание однопалубника и остальных (не понял зачем его отдельно обрабатывали). Кнопки теперь эквивалентные, но мне было лень переделывать. Так что сами, к примеру, на их место поставьте счётчики оставшихся кораблей (что сейчас во всплывающих подсказках) и сделаете одну общую кнопку.

Я добавил в ваш класс `Player()` ещё и данные о кораблях `ships'. Этот массив содержит все корабли с координатами всех их частей и длиной. При попадании, у соответствующего корабля уменьшается длина, и корабль считается убитым при достижении нулевой длины.

Ну и схлопнул в циклы кучу однотипных строчек. Хотя в этом направлении ещё работать и работать. *Подсказка: чтобы не плодить кучу однотипных простых переменных и писать кучи похожих строк кода - чаще используйте списки и словари, по которым потом можно итерироваться в циклах или адресоваться по индексу безо всяких `if`.*

```
import sys
import re
from random import randrange
import sqlite3

from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap, QIcon
from PyQt5.QtCore import QBasicTimer, QCoreApplication

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, \
    QStackedWidget, QMessageBox, QInputDialog, QTableWidgetItem, QAction
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

def natural_key(string_):
    return [int(s) if s.isdigit() else s for s in re.split(r'(\d+)', string_)]


class Ui_MainWindow_ready(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(960, 540)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.horizontalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_2")
        self.playerLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(16)
        self.playerLabel.setFont(font)
        self.playerLabel.setObjectName("playerLabel")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.playerLabel)
        self.gridLayout.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_2, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.readyButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(24)
        self.readyButton.setFont(font)
        self.readyButton.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.readyButton.setObjectName("readyButton")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.readyButton, 0, 2, 1, 2)
        self.verticalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout_2.setObjectName("verticalLayout_2")
        self.linkorButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        font.setItalic(False)
        font.setStrikeOut(False)
        self.linkorButton.setFont(font)
        self.linkorButton.setObjectName("linkorButton")
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.linkorButton)
        self.kreyserButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.kreyserButton.setFont(font)
        self.kreyserButton.setObjectName("kreyserButton")
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.kreyserButton)
        self.esminecButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.esminecButton.setFont(font)
        self.esminecButton.setObjectName("esminecButton")
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.esminecButton)
        self.torpedButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.torpedButton.setFont(font)
        self.torpedButton.setObjectName("torpedButton")
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.torpedButton)
        self.gridLayout.addLayout(self.verticalLayout_2, 1, 3, 1, 1)
        self.boardMap = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self.centralwidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.boardMap.setFont(font)
        self.boardMap.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAsNeeded)
        self.boardMap.setSizeAdjustPolicy(QtWidgets.QAbstractScrollArea.AdjustIgnored)
        self.boardMap.setObjectName("boardMap")
        self.boardMap.setColumnCount(10)
        self.boardMap.setRowCount(10)
        for i in range(10):
            item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
            self.boardMap.setVerticalHeaderItem(i, item)
            item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
            self.boardMap.setHorizontalHeaderItem(i, item)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.boardMap, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.linkorImage = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.linkorImage.setText("")
        self.linkorImage.setObjectName("linkorImage")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.linkorImage)
        self.kreyserImage = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.kreyserImage.setText("")
        self.kreyserImage.setObjectName("kreyserImage")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.kreyserImage)
        self.esminecImage = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.esminecImage.setText("")
        self.esminecImage.setObjectName("esminecImage")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.esminecImage)
        self.torpedImage = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.torpedImage.setText("")
        self.torpedImage.setObjectName("torpedImage")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.torpedImage)
        self.gridLayout.addLayout(self.verticalLayout, 1, 2, 1, 1)
        self.verticalLayout_3 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout_3.setObjectName("verticalLayout_3")
        self.lcdNumber = []
        for i in range(4, 0, -1):
            self.lcdNumber.append(QtWidgets.QLCDNumber(self.centralwidget))
            self.lcdNumber[-1].setProperty("intValue", i)
            self.lcdNumber[-1].setObjectName(f"lcdNumber_{4-i}")
            self.verticalLayout_3.addWidget(self.lcdNumber[-1])
        self.gridLayout.addLayout(self.verticalLayout_3, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(8)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label, 0, 1, 1, 1)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 960, 26))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.playerLabel.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Игрок1"))
        self.readyButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Я  готов"))
        for w in [self.linkorButton, self.kreyserButton, self.esminecButton, self.torpedButton]:
            w.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Поставить корабль"))
        for i in range(10):
            item = self.boardMap.verticalHeaderItem(i)
            item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", str(i+1)))
        for i, c in enumerate("ABCDEFGHIJ"):
            item = self.boardMap.horizontalHeaderItem(i)
            item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", c))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Количество ячеек."))


class Ui_MainWindow_pvp(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(960, 577)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")
        self.board1Label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(16)
        self.board1Label.setFont(font)
        self.board1Label.setObjectName("board1Label")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.board1Label)
        self.linkorP1 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.linkorP1.setText("")
        self.linkorP1.setObjectName("linkorP1")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.linkorP1)
        self.kreyserP1 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.kreyserP1.setText("")
        self.kreyserP1.setObjectName("kreyserP1")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.kreyserP1)
        self.esminecP1 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.esminecP1.setText("")
        self.esminecP1.setObjectName("esminecP1")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.esminecP1)
        self.torpedP1 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.torpedP1.setText("")
        self.torpedP1.setObjectName("torpedP1")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.torpedP1)
        self.gridLayout.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.horizontalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_2")
        self.linkorP2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.linkorP2.setText("")
        self.linkorP2.setObjectName("linkorP2")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.linkorP2)
        self.kreyserP2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.kreyserP2.setText("")
        self.kreyserP2.setObjectName("kreyserP2")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.kreyserP2)
        self.esminecP2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.esminecP2.setText("")
        self.esminecP2.setObjectName("esminecP2")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.esminecP2)
        self.torpedP2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.torpedP2.setText("")
        self.torpedP2.setObjectName("torpedP2")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.torpedP2)
        self.board2Label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(16)
        self.board2Label.setFont(font)
        self.board2Label.setObjectName("board2Label")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.board2Label)
        self.gridLayout.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_2, 0, 5, 1, 1)
        self.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.tableWidget.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(441, 461))
        self.tableWidget.setObjectName("tableWidget")
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(10)
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(10)
        for i in range(10):
            item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
            self.tableWidget.setVerticalHeaderItem(i, item)
            item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
            self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(i, item)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.tableWidget, 1, 0, 1, 3)
        spacerItem = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(40, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.gridLayout.addItem(spacerItem, 0, 1, 1, 1)
        self.vsLable = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Digital Counter 7")
        font.setPointSize(36)
        self.vsLable.setFont(font)
        self.vsLable.setText("")
        self.vsLable.setObjectName("vsLable")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.vsLable, 0, 2, 1, 2)
        self.tableWidget_2 = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.tableWidget_2.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(441, 461))
        self.tableWidget_2.setObjectName("tableWidget_2")
        self.tableWidget_2.setColumnCount(10)
        self.tableWidget_2.setRowCount(10)
        for i in range(10):
            item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
            self.tableWidget_2.setVerticalHeaderItem(i, item)
            item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
            self.tableWidget_2.setHorizontalHeaderItem(i, item)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.tableWidget_2, 1, 3, 1, 3)
        spacerItem1 = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(40, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.gridLayout.addItem(spacerItem1, 0, 4, 1, 1)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 960, 26))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Game PVP"))
        for i in range(10):
            item = self.tableWidget.verticalHeaderItem(i)
            item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", str(i+1)))
            item = self.tableWidget_2.verticalHeaderItem(i)
            item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", str(i+1)))
        for i, c in enumerate("ABCDEFGHIJ"):
            item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(i)
            item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", c))
            item = self.tableWidget_2.horizontalHeaderItem(i)
            item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", c))


COORDS = dict(("ABCDEFGHIJ"[x]+str(y+1), (y, x)) for x in range(10) for y in range(10))
players = []



def new_cell_mul():  # Когда ставлю звёздочку в QTableWidget
    cell_mul = QTableWidgetItem("*")
    cell_mul.setFlags(QtCore.Qt.ItemIsSelectable | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled)
    return cell_mul


def new_cell_x():  # Когда ставлю крестик в QTableWidget
    cell_x = QTableWidgetItem("X")
    cell_x.setFlags(QtCore.Qt.ItemIsSelectable | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled)
    return cell_x


def new_cell_dot():  # Когда ставлю точку в QTableWidget
    cell_dot = QTableWidgetItem(".")
    cell_dot.setFlags(QtCore.Qt.ItemIsSelectable | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled)
    return cell_dot



class ReadyMain(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow_ready):
    """Меню подготовления к самой игре"""

    def __init__(self, parent=None):             
        super(ReadyMain, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.map = SeaMap(self.boardMap)
        self.new_count()  # Обновление переменных-счётчиков
        self.new_map()  # Обновление карты


        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        # Задаю цвет и форму кнопкам
        for w in [self.linkorButton, self.kreyserButton, self.esminecButton, self.torpedButton]:
            w.setStyleSheet("color: white; background-color: #b6afa9;"
                            "border-radius: 10px;")
            w.clicked.connect(self.setShip)

        self.readyButton.setStyleSheet("color: white; background-color: #b6afa9;"
                                       "border-radius: 10px;")
        self.readyButton.clicked.connect(self.start)


    def new_map(self):  # Метод создаёт(обновляет) карту
        for i in range(self.boardMap.columnCount()):
            for j in range(self.boardMap.rowCount()):
                self.boardMap.setItem(i, j, new_cell_dot())
        self.boardMap.resizeColumnsToContents()
        self.boardMap.resizeRowsToContents()

        self.boardMap.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(QtWidgets.QHeaderView.Stretch)

        self.boardMap.verticalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(QtWidgets.QHeaderView.Stretch)

    def new_db(self, who):  # Занесения данных в базу данных
        self.con = sqlite3.connect("Players.db")
        self.cur = self.con.cursor()
        for i, j in COORDS.items():
            self.cur.execute(f"""UPDATE {who} SET {i[0]} = '{str(self.boardMap.item(*COORDS[i]).text())}'
                         WHERE id={int(i[1:])}""")
        self.con.commit()


    def start(self):
        """Если Игрок1 нажал кнопку,
        то Игрок2 начинает заполнять данные.
        Иначе начинает игру"""
        # Проверка, все ли корабли поставлены
        if any(self.count.values()):
            self.error("Вы не поставили все корабли")
            return
        if self.sender().text() == 'Я  готов':
            self.new_db("Player1")
            players.append(Player('Player1', self.boardMap, self.ships))  # Добавление в список игрока
            players
            self.readyButton.setText("Я готов")
            self.playerLabel.setText("Игрок 2")
            self.new_count()  # Обновление переменных-счётчиков
            self.new_map()  # Обновление карты



        else:
            self.new_db("Player2")
            players.append(Player('Player2', self.boardMap, self.ships))  # Добавление в список игрока
            windows.setCurrentIndex(1)

    def new_count(self):  # Создание(обновление) переменных-счётчиков
        self.count = { 'L': 1, 'K': 2, 'E': 3, 'T': 4}
        self.ships = { 'L': [], 'K': [], 'E': [], 'T': []}
        for who in "TEKL":
            {'L': self.linkorButton,
             'K': self.kreyserButton,
             'E': self.esminecButton,
             'T': self.torpedButton}[who].setToolTip(f"{self.count[who]} left")

    def coords_is_right(self, new_coords, num, mode='dual'):
        # проверка на правильность введённых координат
        new_coords[0] = new_coords[0].upper()
        new_coords[1] = new_coords[1].upper()
        if mode != 'v':
            return (COORDS[new_coords[1]][0] - COORDS[new_coords[0]][0] == 0 and
                    COORDS[new_coords[1]][1] - COORDS[new_coords[0]][1] == num) or \
                   (COORDS[new_coords[1]][0] - COORDS[new_coords[0]][0] == num and
                    COORDS[new_coords[1]][1] - COORDS[new_coords[0]][1] == 0)
        return (COORDS[new_coords[1]][0] - COORDS[new_coords[0]][0] == num and
                COORDS[new_coords[1]][1] - COORDS[new_coords[0]][1] == 0)

    def check(self, c1, c2, i, num):
        # Проверка, если в координатах есть * или X,
        if num == 1:
            return (str(self.boardMap.item(c1 + i, c2).text()) == "*" or
                    str(self.boardMap.item(c1 + i, c2).text()) == "X")
        return (str(self.boardMap.item(c1, c2 + i).text()) == "*" or
                str(self.boardMap.item(c1, c2 + i).text()) == "X")

    def error(self, text="Недопустимый размер или форма корабля."):  # Вызов ошибки
        QMessageBox.critical(self, 'Ошибка!', text)

    def setShipByType(self, coords, num, who):  # Создание любого корабля на поле
        error = False
        new_coords = coords.split('-')
        if self.coords_is_right(new_coords, num):
            vertical = self.coords_is_right(new_coords, num, 'v')
            c1, c2 = COORDS[new_coords[0]][0], COORDS[new_coords[0]][1]
            for i in range(num + 1):
                if self.check(c1, c2, i, 1 if vertical else 2):
                    self.error("Сюда нельзя поставить корабль")
                    return
            coords_as_num = []
            for i in range(num + 1):
                if not vertical:
                    self.boardMap.setItem(c1, c2 + i, new_cell_x())
                    coords_as_num.append((c1, c2 + i))
                    if i == num:
                        self.map.shoot(c1, c2 + i, "sink")
                else:
                    self.boardMap.setItem(c1 + i, c2, new_cell_x())
                    coords_as_num.append((c1 + i, c2))
                    if i == num:
                        self.map.shoot(c1 + i, c2, 'sink')
            self.count[who] -= 1
            self.ships[who].append([coords_as_num, {'L': 4, 'K': 3, 'E': 2, 'T': 1}[who]])
            {'L': self.linkorButton,
             'K': self.kreyserButton,
             'E': self.esminecButton,
             'T': self.torpedButton}[who].setToolTip(f"{self.count[who]} left")

        else:
            self.error()



    def setShip(self):  # Создание корабля
        items = sorted(["ABCDEFGHIJ"[item.column()]+str(item.row()+1) for item in self.boardMap.selectedItems()], key=natural_key)
        n = len(items)
        if 1 <= n <= 4:
            if self.count[' TEKL'[n]] == 0:
                self.error("Все корабли этого типа поставлены")
                return
            try:
                self.setShipByType(f"{items[0]}-{items[-1]}", n-1, " TEKL"[n])
            except BaseException:
                self.error()
        else:
            self.error()


class PVPMain(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow_pvp):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(PVPMain, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)


        self.turn = "Игрок1"  # Очередь первого игрока

        self.map = []
        self.map.append(SeaMap(self.tableWidget))
        self.map.append(SeaMap(self.tableWidget_2))

        self.new_boards()  # Создание игрового поля

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.tableWidget.cellClicked[int, int].connect(self.course1)
        self.tableWidget_2.cellClicked[int, int].connect(self.course2)


        self.board1Label.setText("Игрок 1")
        self.board2Label.setText("Игрок 2")
        self.board1Label.setStyleSheet("background-color: #B22222")
        self.board2Label.setStyleSheet("background-color: #1E90FF")


        self.tableWidget.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(QtWidgets.QHeaderView.Stretch)

        self.tableWidget.verticalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(QtWidgets.QHeaderView.Stretch)


        self.tableWidget_2.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(QtWidgets.QHeaderView.Stretch)

        self.tableWidget_2.verticalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(QtWidgets.QHeaderView.Stretch)

    def new_boards(self):
        for i in range(self.tableWidget.columnCount()):
            for j in range(self.tableWidget.rowCount()):
                self.tableWidget.setItem(i, j, new_cell_dot())
        for i in range(self.tableWidget_2.columnCount()):
            for j in range(self.tableWidget_2.rowCount()):
                self.tableWidget_2.setItem(i, j, new_cell_dot())
        self.tableWidget.resizeColumnsToContents()
        self.tableWidget.resizeRowsToContents()
        self.tableWidget_2.resizeColumnsToContents()
        self.tableWidget_2.resizeRowsToContents()

    def change_of_course(self):  # Смена хода
        if self.turn == "Игрок1":
            self.turn = "Игрок2"
            self.board2Label.setStyleSheet("background-color: #B22222")
            self.board1Label.setStyleSheet("background-color: #1E90FF")
            players[0], players[1] = players[1], players[0]
        elif self.turn == "Игрок2":
            self.turn = "Игрок1"
            self.board1Label.setStyleSheet("background-color: #B22222")
            self.board2Label.setStyleSheet("background-color: #1E90FF")
            players[0], players[1] = players[1], players[0]


    def info(self, text="Координаты правильные"):  # Информационное табло
        QMessageBox.information(self, "INFO", text)

    def error(self, text="Вы уже стреляли в эту клетку."):  # Вызов ошибки
        QMessageBox.critical(self, 'Ошибка!', text)

    def check(self):
        if all(players[1].board[i][j] == 0 for i in range(10) for j in range(10)):
            self.info(f"Выиграл {self.turn}!")
            windows.setCurrentIndex(5)
            return

    def course1(self, c1, c2):
        self.course(c1, c2, 1)

    def course2(self, c1, c2):
        self.course(c1, c2, 2)

    def course(self, r, c, num):  # Ход
        if self.turn[-1] == '1' and num == 2 or self.turn[-1] == '2' and num == 1:
            flag = True
            coord = (r, c)
        else:
            flag = False

        if num == 1:
            if str(self.tableWidget.item(r, c).text()) == "*" or str(self.tableWidget.item(r, c).text()) == "X" :
                self.error()
                return
        else:
            if str(self.tableWidget_2.item(r, c).text()) == "*" or str(self.tableWidget_2.item(r, c).text()) == "X" :
                self.error()
                return

        if flag:
            if self.dot_or_notdot((r, c)):
                dead = self.shootAndCheckIfShipIsDead((r, c))
                what = 'sink' if dead else  'hit'
                pl = 1 if self.turn[-1] == '1' else 0
                self.map[pl].shoot(r, c, what)
                players[1].board[r][c] = 0
                self.info("Корабль потоплен!" if dead else "Попадание!")

                self.check()
            else:
                pl = 1 if self.turn[-1] == '1' else 0
                self.map[pl].shoot(r, c, 'miss')
                self.info("Промах!")

                self.change_of_course()
        else:
            QMessageBox.critical(self, "Ошибка!", "Не ваша очередь!")

    def dot_or_notdot(self, coord):  # Проверка попал, не попал
        new_coord = None
        for key, value in COORDS.items():
            if value == coord:
                new_coord = (key, value)
                break
        con = sqlite3.connect("Players.db")
        cur = con.cursor()
        result = cur.execute(
            f"""SELECT {new_coord[0][0]} FROM Player{players[1].who[-1]}
            WHERE id={new_coord[1][0] + 1}""").fetchone()
        if result[0] == "." or result[0] == "*":
            return False
        return True

    def shootAndCheckIfShipIsDead(self, pos):  # Стреляем по кораблю и проверяем, потопил или ранил
        x, y = pos
        if 0 <= x < 10 and 0 <= y < 10:
            if players[1].board[x][y] == 1:
                for who in "TEKL":
                    for ship in players[1].ships[who]:
                        if pos in ship[0]:
                            ship[1] -= 1
                            return ship[1] == 0
        return False




class Player:
    def __init__(self, who, map, ships):
        self.who = who
        self.board = []
        self.ships = ships
        for i in range(10):
            self.board.append([])
            for j in range(10):
                self.board[i].append(0)
        for i in range(10):
            for j in range(10):
                if str(map.item(i, j).text()) == 'X':
                    self.board[i][j] = 1


class SeaMap:
    def __init__(self, board):
        self.map = board

    def shoot(self, row, col, result):
        if result == 'miss':
            self.map.setItem(row, col, new_cell_mul())
        elif result == 'hit':
            self.map.setItem(row, col, new_cell_x())
        elif result == 'sink':
            for i in range(row - 1, row + 2):
                for j in range(col - 1, col + 2):
                    if 0 <= i < 10 and 0 <= j < 10:
                        if str(self.map.item(i, j).text()) == '.':
                            self.map.setItem(i, j, new_cell_mul())
            self.map.setItem(row, col, new_cell_x())
            for j in range(10):
                if str(self.map.item(row, j).text()) == 'X':
                    col = j
                    for i in range(row - 1, row + 2):
                        for u in range(col - 1, col + 2):
                            if 0 <= i < 10 and 0 <= u < 10:
                                if str(self.map.item(i, u).text()) == '.':
                                    self.map.setItem(i, u, new_cell_mul())
            for v in range(10):
                if str(self.map.item(v, col).text()) == 'X':
                    row = v
                    for v in range(row - 1, row + 2):
                        for u in range(col - 1, col + 2):
                            if 0 <= v < 10 and 0 <= u < 10:
                                if str(self.map.item(v, u).text()) == '.':
                                    self.map.setItem(v, u, new_cell_mul())


if __name__ == '__main__': 
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)


    ready_window = ReadyMain()
    pvp_window = PVPMain()

    windows = QStackedWidget()


    windows.addWidget(ready_window)  # 0
    windows.addWidget(pvp_window)  # 1


    windows.setWindowTitle("Морской бой")
    windows.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

[image: Ранен] [image: Убит]